# Disable blockcache for large scan in Hbase

Tags: hbase

I have been reading about I should disable blockcache in Hbase for large scan. I thought that it was because you get a better performance in the large scans since you don't use GC and save time that you spend loading the blockcache, but I read benchmark where people got about the same performance.

I think that if I don't use blockcache, I should gain time because GC doesn't have to execute so often. I found a question from Cloudera about that as well, and I don't really like any of the possible responses for the test question, and I guess it should be the truth.
So, do you get a better performance for large(full table) scans if you disabled your blockcache? what is the reason?

Answer (score 7):

Hbase has two cache structures

1. MemStore
2. BlockCache

### MemStore

Used in Writes.
HBase uses memStore to buffer values before writing them to disk as a new storage file.

### Block Cache

Used in Reads.
Each HBase region server has a block cache that efficiently retains recently accessed
data for subsequent reads of contiguous information.

---

As HBase reads entire blocks of data for efficient I/O usage, it retains these blocks
in an block cache so that subsequent reads do not need any disk operation.

If you are scanning a large table with block cache enabled, the data is cached in memory. Since the entire table won't fit into cache, GC will be executed frequently which may decrease the performance.

If you are not going to read the same data again and again, it is of no use to cache it. In this case enabling block cache will only decrease the performance

- Each read checks for the data in cache and goes for disk I/O, and the data is cached (which will not be used again)
- When the Block cache is full, clean up has to be done.

This will increase the use of memory and CPU thus decreasing the performance.

Block Cache improves the performance when the same data is read frequently. It doesn't help in large table scan.

Answer (score 2):

While performing a full table scan it is advisable to set `setBlockCacheEnabled(false);` as the entire table would not fit into the block cache.